# when trying to use aws-sdk with http in nodejs i am getting InvalidParameterType error

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I created the below function that is supposed to check if there is a value in a simple db domain.

when i call this independently i am getting back the correct results but if i call it as part of the http server's code i am getting InvalidParameterType error.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(requester, response) {
    var parsedUrl = url_mod.parse(requester.url.toLowerCase());
    if (parsedUrl.pathname == "/") {
      response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      });
      response.end("Unicorn11 was here\n");
    } else if (parsedUrl.pathname == "/clientlist/") {
      response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      });
      response.end("user does not exist\n");
      checkExists();
    } else {
      response.writeHead(404, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      });
      response.end("42!&nbsp;:) \n");
    }
  });
  server.listen(8000);
  console.log("Server running at port 8000");

function checkExists() {
console.log("checkExists");
simpledb.select(params = {
'SelectExpression': 'select * from xxx where x = "y"'
}, checkExistsCallback);
};

function checkExistsCallback(err, data) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
//return false;
};
```

any idea why this is happening?
regards
Abhishek

Comment: In `function checkExistsCallback(err, data)` the return type is commented. The 2nd parameter type is `Boolean` in `select` function. Is that the issue?